# how intercept the form submit data from MailChimp plugin Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp

I need to intercept the form submit data from `MailChimp` plugin WordPress and save them into database. But I don't know how  to intercept the form submit data using `MailChimp` plugin.
Any advice will be appreciated!